# How do I display the Site Name on my master page?

Tags: branding, custom-masterpage

I am using  the [starter master pages](http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex, and I want to have the current SiteName on each page. What is the best way to do that dynamically?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Insert [`<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.projectproperty.aspx) into the masterpage where you want it.

Or if you want it like the default v4.master with a being in the PlaceHolderSiteName ContentPlaceHolder as a link, then use

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: Perfect for me!

Answer (score 3):

There is a out of the box content placeholder containing the site name that can be placed inside your masterpage. I believe Randy has it included in the block of content placeholders at the bottom of the page, and you can just bring it up to where you want it.

`<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server"/>`

Comment: I know. I tried that but it doesn't return any data...

Comment: Confirm your site has a name: Site Settings -> Title, Description and Icon.

Comment: Inserting an empty ContentPlaceHolder will require every PageLayout/Page to add the ProjectProperty inside

Comment: Title, Description and Icon have data.

Comment: As Per stated (and I didn't really give you a full solution), `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server"/>` gives you the placeholder that you'd fill with the property. If that placeholder exists on your masterpage or page layout, then you can fill it with `<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />` which will return the site title from the "Title, Description, and Icon" configuration.