# How To Dynamically Display Site Title On Application Page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, application-pages

I'm using a custom application page and was wanting to know, how do I dynamically display a sites title within my custom application page?

Answer (score 1):

I think we can use SharePoint content place holders in application pages. You can use the following

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

check the link for how it is done in master page
[How do I display the Site Name on my master page?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37992/how-do-i-display-the-site-name-on-my-master-page)